# How can I add sprite image from a set of sprites which have different properties for each sprite?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

In my application one player and 10 targets are there. Each target appears one after the other (from target1 to target10). It's a shooting game. If we hit the first target then second target will come. The targets have properties like name, speedOfGunDraw, probability   to hit the player, speedOfFire.
What should I do to make them appear one after the other with these properties. I am using CCMenuItem for the target. I am using a sprite for the player. Please give me idea to do this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your question: With Cocos2D, your scene would create the sprites. You can get the current running scene and send it a message ("I'm shot", for instance). This can be done through the director.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]; // returns a pointer to the running scene
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] someoneShotMe: self]; // will message the scene that you're shot.
```

Alternatively, if your scene is not controlling things, set the object your wish to be informed as a delegate, upon creation of the "enemy".

```
Enemy * enemy1 = [[Enemy alloc] init];
[enemy1 setDelegate: self];

// and then from your enemy object, you call a message on the delegate
[self->delegate someoneShotMe: self];
```

I think you're over complicating this because you don't use MVC in there.

You should not subclass sprites to give them more functionality beyond the "view".

Properties like `probabilityToHitPlayer` don't affect the view directly, so shouldn't be stored in a sprite.

Create a new class, like `Enemy` (subclass of `NSObject`), which contains a sprite, along with other properties like `probabilityToHitPlayer`

Enemy can then handle the logic (it is a controller) while Sprite handles the visible parts.

Also, using menu items because they have touch detection? Not pretty. Instead, look into CCTargetedTouchDelegate.